# Allow user to select pre-set or optional parameters azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, pipeline

I am currently defining a parameter within my azure pipeline as follows:

```
parameters:
- name: nodeSize
  displayName: nodeSize
  type: string
  default: size1
  values:
  - size1
  - size2
```

The result of this, is that when attempting to run the pipeline the user is presented with a drop down menu that allows them to choose one of the defined values, as shown bellow:

[image]

My goal is to create my parameters in a way that the user can select from the dropdown box, OR enter their own value. So the resulting dropdown menu would like like:

- Size 1
- Size 2
- <Users optional input>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that this is not possible. You can create two parameters:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: nodeSize
  displayName: nodeSize
  type: string
  default: size1
  values:
  - size1
  - size2
parameters:
- name: customSize
  displayName: customNodeSize
  type: string
  default: ' '
```

and then check if `customSize` size was provided. I understood that this is far away from perfect. But we are limited to functionality we have now.

Comment: @MantyQuestions Can you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful for you?